# photo does not show with image slider

Tags: html, css, image, slider

```css
@keyframes drunk2anim {
0% {
    opacity: 0;
}
17% {
    opacity: 0;
}
33% {
    opacity: 1;
}
50% {
    opacity: 1;
}
67% {
    opacity: 0;
}
100% {
    opacity: 0;
}
}

@keyframes drunk3anim {
0% {
    opacity: 0;
}
17% {
    opacity: 0;
}
33% {
    opacity: 0;
}
50% {
    opacity: 1;
}
67% {
    opacity: 1;
}
100% {
    opacity: 0;
}
}

.drunk1 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    top: 150px;
    left: 200px;
}

.drunk2 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    top: 150px;
    left: 200px;
    animation: drunk3anim 10s infinite;
}

.drunk3 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    top: 150px;
    left: 200px;
    animation: drunk3anim 10s infinite;
}
```

```html
                <div class="numberone">
                <img class="drunk1" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3c/PEO-drunk.svg/64px-PEO-drunk.svg.png">
            </div>

            <div class="numberone">
                <img class="drunk2" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3c/PEO-drunk.svg/64px-PEO-drunk.svg.png">
            </div>

            <div class="numberthree"> 
                <img class="drunk2" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3c/PEO-drunk.svg/64px-PEO-drunk.svg.png">
            </div>
```

I was just creating a simple image slider, everything seems to be working apart from the fact the one image does not show up in the slider drunk002. If i take away position absolute on the css then all the images show up and you can see the animation working so how become when they are all stacked one of them does not show up? what am i doing wrong thanks.....

Comment: Without seeing the actual image in a functional demo [mcve] there's not much we can tell

Comment: BUT, given that they are jpegs, if you stack them, you wouldn't be able to see through the top one...if that's what you mean.

Comment: create jsfiddle please and we can help you

Comment: i slides fine just one image doesnt show but unstack them all images are there

Comment: Why did you make 2 different classes? drunk2 and drunk3 is the same. So you need only one of them.

Comment: I got it sorted sorry to bother thanks for the help was a simple typo